# convert the dictionary of tuples and float values to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a formatted data as dict[tuple[str, str], list[float]]
i want to convert it into a pandas dataframe

Example data:
{('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656]}

i tried using some data manipulations using split functions.
Expecting:-

[image]

Comment: Do all tuples have the same length? The same question concerning all items of the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656], ('C','D'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656]}
title = []
heading = []
num_col1 = []
num_col2 = []
for key, val in data.items():
    title.append(key[0])
    heading.append(key[1])
    num_col1.append(val[0])
    num_col2.append(val[1])
data_ = {'title':title, 'heading':heading, 'num_col1':num_col1, 'num_col2':num_col1}
pd.DataFrame(data_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be to construct your `Index` manually. For this we can use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples` since your dictionary keys are stored as tuples. From there we just need to store the values of the dictionary into the body of a `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656]}
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(data.keys(), names=['title', 'heading'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), index=index).reset_index()

print(df)
  title heading         0         1
0     A       B -0.008035  0.008542
```

If you want chained operation, you can do:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656]}
df = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    .pipe(lambda d:
        d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.index, names=['title', 'heading']))
    )
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
  title heading         0         1
0     A       B -0.008035  0.008542
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which works also if the tuples and lists vary in length:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_records([x for x in d.keys()],
                                     columns=['title', 'h1', 'h2']),
           pd.DataFrame.from_records([x[1] for x in d.items()])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  title h1    h2         0         1    2
0     A  B  None -0.008035  0.008542  NaN
1     C  B     D -0.010351  1.008542  5.0
```

Data input:

```
d = {('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656],
     ('C','B', 'D'): [-0.01035100996494293,1.008541940711438656, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the keys and values as you iterate the dictionary items. Pandas will see 4 values which it will make into a row.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {('A','B'): [-0.008035100996494293,0.008541940711438656]}
>>> pd.DataFrame(((*d[0], *d[1]) for d in data.items()), columns=("Title", "Heading", "Foo", "Bar"))
  Title Heading       Foo       Bar
0     A       B -0.008035  0.008542
```